# Find a path through a maze in C++ recursion error

Tags: c++, recursion, maze

I'm trying to write a function which finds a path through a maze. There is another function reads the maze from a text file. For now the function I wrote to find the path works fine when the maze is 20 rows and 20 columns but it does not work with any other variations. Here is is the code I've wrote for the function:

```
void find_paths(maze m, int r, int c, int rows, int cols) {
  if (r == rows - 1)
    display(m, rows, cols);
  else {
    if (r > 0 && m[r - 1][c] == space) // UP
    {
      m[r - 1][c] = path;
      find_paths(m, r - 1, c, rows, cols);
      m[r - 1][c] = space;
    }
    if (m[r + 1][c] == space) // DOWN
    {
      m[r + 1][c] = path;
      find_paths(m, r + 1, c, rows, cols);
      m[r + 1][c] = space;
    }
    if (m[r][c - 1] == space) // LEFT
    {
      m[r][c - 1] = path;
      find_paths(m, r, c - 1, rows, cols);
      m[r][c - 1] = space;
    }
    if (m[r][c + 1] == space) // RIGHT
    {
      m[r][c + 1] = path;
      find_paths(m, r, c + 1, rows, cols);
      m[r][c + 1] = space;
    }
  }
}
```

space is a char =' '
path is a char ='.'

And here is a screenshot for the file of the maze that the program reads.

[image: maze.txt]

And here is a screenshot for the program execution.

[image: execution]

I'm new to C++ hope you can help me.

Comment: It solves other mazes but it keeps printing them at least 8 times or keep printing them and the program does not end.

Comment: There is a conception problem in your algorithm, because it will never end, finding many and many solutions until infinity. And I think you should debug your program and you will find what line causes problems.

Comment: Put together a short complete example and include the maze you're having trouble with as text in your question. Otherwise it's just a guess. You'd probably be better off using a debugger and figuring out why your recursion never ends. I don't see a clear path for that, perhaps you want a return after display.

Comment: Look up "depth first search" and "breadth first search". Or flood-fill, since that's what you are doing here. Basically, you need to detect when you have already been there.

Comment: How is maze declared? It should know its rows and cols, making those redundant. It looks like you are making a copy of the entire maze at every single recursion.

Comment: Look at this question on Code Review and my answer there: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/186107/151754

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much wrong (although it could be done more efficiently).  Most likely it's not working because you are missing bounds checks for columns.
Since you allow the columns to obtain any value, you're probably going outside the bounds of the maze.
Your other problem is that when you reach the solution, you still have all the other recursive paths being taken.

This is just a minor change from your code and should work:

```
bool done = false;

void find_paths(maze m, int r, int c, int rows, int cols) {
  if(done) {
      return;
  }
  if (r == rows - 1) {
    display(m, rows, cols);
    done = true;
  } else {
    if (r > 0 && m[r - 1][c] == space) // UP
    {
      m[r - 1][c] = path;
      find_paths(m, r - 1, c, rows, cols);
      m[r - 1][c] = space;
    }
    if (m[r + 1][c] == space) // DOWN
    {
      m[r + 1][c] = path;
      find_paths(m, r + 1, c, rows, cols);
      m[r + 1][c] = space;
    }
    if (c > 0 && m[r][c - 1] == space) // LEFT
    {
      m[r][c - 1] = path;
      find_paths(m, r, c - 1, rows, cols);
      m[r][c - 1] = space;
    }
    if (c < cols && m[r][c + 1] == space) // RIGHT
    {
      m[r][c + 1] = path;
      find_paths(m, r, c + 1, rows, cols);
      m[r][c + 1] = space;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment by Benjamin Barrois you need a way to know that you checked out a route and if so not take it again.

I would suggest another character than the '.' (path) to distinguish dead-ends from the actual solution although even that is not exactly enough.

So I would add a variable named `visited = 'x';` and use that on return.

Also, you check `r > 0` in the first test (UP) but you did not check any such limit in the other `if()` (DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT). Although if you have the correct characters there, it will work (i.e. it will hit a wall first) but if that's not the case, you'll start hitting the wrong characters.

```
void find_paths(maze m, int r, int c, int rows, int cols) {
  if (r == rows - 1)
    display(m, rows, cols);
  else {
    if (r > 0 && m[r - 1][c] == space) // UP
    {
      m[r - 1][c] = path;
      find_paths(m, r - 1, c, rows, cols);
      m[r - 1][c] = visited;
    }
    if (r + 1 < rows && m[r + 1][c] == space) // DOWN
    {
      m[r + 1][c] = path;
      find_paths(m, r + 1, c, rows, cols);
      m[r + 1][c] = visited;
    }
    if (c > 0 && m[r][c - 1] == space) // LEFT
    {
      m[r][c - 1] = path;
      find_paths(m, r, c - 1, rows, cols);
      m[r][c - 1] = visited;
    }
    if (c + 1 < cols && m[r][c + 1] == space) // RIGHT
    {
      m[r][c + 1] = path;
      find_paths(m, r, c + 1, rows, cols);
      m[r][c + 1] = visited;
    }
  }
}
```

That being said, your current algorithm doesn't stop when it finds a solution since it is recursive, it will go on forever. If you want to be able to bail out, your function needs to return true (success!) or false (continue search).

Although the idea to use a recursive mechanism can be useful to find all the solutions and especially (if you were to calculate that) the length of the solution so you return only the shorter solution (which is often what a maze search is about.)

```
bool find_paths(maze m, int r, int c, int rows, int cols) {
  if (r == rows - 1) {
    display(m, rows, cols);
    return true;
  }
  else {
    if (r > 0 && m[r - 1][c] == space) // UP
    {
      m[r - 1][c] = path;
      if(find_paths(m, r - 1, c, rows, cols)) {
        return true;
      }
      m[r - 1][c] = visited;
    }
    if (r + 1 < rows && m[r + 1][c] == space) // DOWN
    {
      m[r + 1][c] = path;
      if(find_paths(m, r + 1, c, rows, cols) {
        return true;
      }
      m[r + 1][c] = visited;
    }
    if (c > 0 && m[r][c - 1] == space) // LEFT
    {
      m[r][c - 1] = path;
      if(find_paths(m, r, c - 1, rows, cols) {
        return true;
      }
      m[r][c - 1] = visited;
    }
    if (c + 1 < cols && m[r][c + 1] == space) // RIGHT
    {
      m[r][c + 1] = path;
      if(find_paths(m, r, c + 1, rows, cols) {
        return true;
      }
      m[r][c + 1] = visited;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

As a side note, this is not specific to C++.

Comment: You don't know how maze is defined. This could very well be a local copy (at EVERY SINGLE recursion call) in which case modifying it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Now it works but when I try different mazes it does not work!

Comment: @MarwanElSharkawy are you saying that my changes did or did not help? When you say that it does not work, do you mean that it does not find a solution at all or just that it goes on and on and shows you many solutions forever?

Comment: Also, you do not show us the code that calls that `find_paths()` function. Are you sure that the `rows` and `cols` parameters are set properly? Do you set `c` to the entry point properly each time? What about `r`? Is it always set to 0 on entry? That info may help us find your problem.

Comment: This does not work because setting cells to 'visited' affects all recursive paths being taken.  When you backtrack, the maze must be restored to its prior state.

Comment: @SeanF why would you need to re-visit any already visited corner of the maze?!

Comment: Every recursive path represents a single path through the maze.  When you try a path that does not work, and you return from each function call, you move on to other potential paths.  This is an example of backtracking.  By using "visited" in the first path, you prevent any future path from using any of the cells you used in that first path.  You are cutting off all the future tracks.

Comment: This is an exhaustive search, it will eventually try any and all potential paths until it finds the one that works.  By using 'visited' you prevent that from happening.